# kendo ui numeric text hide show

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a kendo numeric text box as follows and I would like to hide and show it depending on other kendo ui control.

My environment.

1. Web application.
2. asp.net mvc VS 2012
3. C#

here is what my control looks like

```
<p>Duration of load =  @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.DurationOfLoadK3)
    .Name("DurationOfLoadK3")
    .Format("#.00")
    .Min(00.00)
    .Spinners(false)
    .Value(1.00)
    )
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#divDurationOfLoadK3").hide();
        });
    </script> 




    <div id="divDurationOfLoadK3">
        Duration of load =  @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.DurationOfLoadK3)
                                .Name("DurationOfLoadK3")
                                .Format("#.00")
                                .Min(00.00)
                                .Spinners(false)
                                .Value(1.00)
                            )

    </div>
```